# How do I add the Arial font to a Docker Windows Container?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, dockerfile

I'm trying to add the Arial font to a Docker Windows image in Docker Desktop v4.13.1.

The arial.ttf file is in the folder Resources/fonts

This is in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./Resources/fonts /windows/fonts
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts' -name 'Arial (TrueType)' -value 'arial.ttf' -type STRING
```

When I try to built I get this error:

> TrueType : The term 'TrueType' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
> if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> At line:1 char:94 + ... crosoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts -name Arial (TrueType) -value ... +                                                          ~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (TrueType:String) [], CommandNot FoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

If i remove the powershell command the image builds. When I run the powershell command inside the container it works too! But not in the Dockerfile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is not valid. See the powershell.exe help for details.

```
powershell /?
```

From reading the examples directly from the help files, you end up here:

```
 ./Resources/fonts /windows/fonts
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command {New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts' -name 'Arial (TrueType)' -value 'arial.ttf' -type STRING}
```

The command must be properly constructed, quoted, braced, etc., or placed in arguments to be executed.

```
EXAMPLES
    PowerShell -PSConsoleFile SqlSnapIn.Psc1
    PowerShell -version 2.0 -NoLogo -InputFormat text -OutputFormat XML
    PowerShell -ConfigurationName AdminRoles
    PowerShell -Command {Get-EventLog -LogName security}
    PowerShell -Command "& {Get-EventLog -LogName security}"
```